# IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I need to develop a web application where users sometime need to perform action with different credential (specifically they are standard domain users, and they need to reset password, unlock user and so on).
I've planned to create 2 services running with privileged credential (by using ASP.NET Impersonation), and a web portal where users access and invoke services (by using Windows Authentication).

Before starting implementation I'm testing credential, but I'm getting a bit confused... If I use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` to check credential, it seems to be correct in services (DOMAIN\admin) and wrong in portal (IIS\APPPOL\DefaultAppPool), while using `User.Identity.Name` returns wrong credential in services (DOMAIN\user doing request) but correct in portal (DOMAIN\user doing request).

Why didn't `User.Identity.Name` return always "final" credential? It seems a bit incoherent... Am I missing something?

Comment: Personally, I never fully understood the `WindowsIdentity` stuff. Instead, I use [my small little class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User), that works very well for ASP.NET, too

Comment: @UweKeim if you don't understand it, should I be concerned about using your class :-p, I jest, I always thought the ommision of a disposable impersonation context was an oversight.

Comment: Note that if you want to use the impersonation context to pass credentials between  3 or more servers that will be multi-hop and you'll need to set up SPNs and use kerberos.

Answer (score -1):

use session not User.Identity!

Comment: Yes... nice statement... Can you explain better what you mean and also give us a few grounds?